# UHF RFID DL920 reader's Inventory command does not work with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, rfid

I have a DL920 UHF RFID reader. I need to use its Inventory command. The command works well with the Demo Software which comes in the box with the reader.

However, I must connect my Nodejs application to get the data. I am using the builtin Nodejs module `net`'s Socket. I have successfully done this for the Active mode of the reader and have properly received data.

The problem is that the Inventory command works only in Answer mode, so I switched to Answer mode. And I have constructed the Inventory command (according to the manual): `[0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0xdb, 0x4b]` (where the data block is empty, reader address is `0x00`, `0x01` is for inventory and the last 2 values are CRC-16 checksum) and sending it to the reader using the `net.Socket().write([0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0xdb, 0x4b])`.

But I am not getting any response from the reader and it does not react when my EPC G2 tags are in the effective field.

What is wrong with my command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inventory looks for tags in the effective field **only at the moment** it was requested.

It seems you are sending the Inventory command once only.
So you need to send the command constantly in some interval.

Something like

```
setInterval(() => { 
    client.write(Buffer.from([0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0xdb, 0x4b], 'hex')); 
}, 100);
```

will work.